# How do i change the color of my navbar that has a fixed position?

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to add "background-color" but that just leaves a big empty gap in between the header img and header nav due to the position.Without the position, the header nav wouldn't be where i want it to be (towards the right)
(I can't use any bootstrap or whatever because its not in my syllabus and im just starting out to code)

This is my code:

```css
header {
  margin-top: auto;
  height: 79px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header img {
  float: left;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  height: 79px;
  left: 542px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="index.html"><img src="images/greylogo.png" alt="E R I" /></a>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li> <a href=#> Home </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="aboutme.html"> About Me </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="events.html"> Events </a></li>
      <li> <a href="contact.html" target="_blank"> Contact Me </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Position the header not the contents...

```css
header {
  height: 79px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background: lightblue
}

header img {
  float: left;
}

header nav {
  float: right;
}

header nav li { 
float:left;   
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="index.html"><img src="images/greylogo.png" alt="E R I" /></a>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li> <a href=#> Home </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="aboutme.html"> About Me </a> </li>
      <li> <a href="events.html"> Events </a></li>
      <li> <a href="contact.html" target="_blank"> Contact Me </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: thank you but when i use that code, the nav just goes to the bottom of the header and not towards the right :(

Comment: Not in the demo it doesn't

Comment: Then you obviously have something else going on. Perhaps another 
 question that actually **demonstrates** the problem. Not an image.

Answer (score -1):

Your CSS is pretty messed up, i recommend you to learn using a library like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) it will make it easy for you to position your components, to answer you question the problem with your navbar is that it has a fixed height(79px) but your list (ul) is larger than 79px.